# How to use Reactive Forms in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I don't understand how FormGroup, FormControl, FormArray works in Angular

The error I have:

```
Type '{ question: FormControl; multi: true; choices: FormArray; }' is not assignable to type 'AbstractControl'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'question' does not 
exist in type 'AbstractControl'.ts(2322)
```

I'm trying to do this:

```
survey: FormGroup;

results = {
  success:"",
  error:""
}

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.survey = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl(['My Quick Survey', Validators.required]),
    questionnaires: new FormArray([{
      question: new FormControl('Ready for a quick survey?'),  //error
      multi:true,
      choices: new FormArray([
        {text: new FormControl('Yes')},   //error
        {text: new FormControl('No')}    //error
      ])
    }])
  })

  console.log(this.survey)
}
```

Currently, I'm doing a syntax like this:

```
survey = {
name:"My Quick Survey",
questionnaires:[{
  question:"Ready for a quick survey?",
  multi:true,
  choices:[
    {text:"Yes"},
    {text:"No"}
  ]
}]  
}
```

So I don't know how to fix error

Thanks

Comment: can you please add errors you said in the posts?

Comment: Yes I add errors

Comment: does this answer your question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59036037/angular-json-to-formbuilder-to-json

Comment: @zef, a Form Array is a FormArray of FormGroups or a FomArray of FormControls (you feed with an array of FormGroups or with an array of FormControls). You're trying feed with **an array of objects**. BTW, if you want to make a some kind of dinamic forms, take account always you has two things: the data to create the form and the form itself

Comment: Share `HTML` code where you are applying `FormControlName`

Answer (score 0):

With use of `FormBuilder` try this piece of code

```
this.survey = this.fb.group({
    name : ["My Quick Survey",[Validators.required]],
    questionnaires : this.fb.array([{
         question  : ["Ready for a quick survey?"],
         multi     : ["true"],
         choices   : [ "Yes"]
}])
});
```

In this snippet  `choices:[{text:"Yes"},{text:"No"}]` you are trying to achieve something that looks like nested `FormArrays` so you either use `this.fb.array([])` again here otherwise you can go with above in which I am going with simple `FormControl`